# how to make .htaccess ignore specific uri part

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I don't know how to make a rewrite condition to obtain the right behaviour.

This is the link i have:

http://www.example.com/**variable**/Known/Uri/ecc

or

http://www.example.com/**variable**

I'd like to ignore the "variable" part and consider only the rest of the uri.
I will consider "variable" only when reading $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].

Comment: What do you exactly mean by: "_ignore the "variable" part and consider only the rest of the uri_"

Comment: i'd like to redirect only internally to:
/Known/Uri/ecc without consider /variable/
"variable" could be everything. It's only string used to select a specific database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[^/]+(.*)$ $1 [L]
```

Comment: `^[^/]+(.*)$` should be more appropriate, since he explicitly mentioned `http://www.example.com/variable` as an example case

Comment: @matt Correct. Updated my post.

Comment: Not found the requested url /p was not found on this server.

Comment: i didn't try the last one

Comment: with ^[^/]+(.*)$ $1 [L] it says internal server error

Comment: @LeonardoPizzoni Check apache error logs, and see what it reports?

Comment: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: i've edited with ^[^/]+(.*)$ $1 [L] in with ^[^/]+(.*)$ $1index.php [L] and now works properly it seems.